# Interesting use-case where a regular array cannot stand-in for a std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

This comes across as an interesting use-case of a std::array over a regular array: somewhere where I cannot change the syntax to work for a regular array (or so I have convinced myself).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, c = 0; cin >> n;
  array<int, 3> tri;
  map<array<int, 3>, int> freq;

  while (n--)
  {
    cin >> tri[0] >> tri[1] >> tri[2];
    sort(begin(tri), end(tri));
    freq[tri]++;
  }

  for (auto i : freq)
  {
    cout << &i.first << ' ' << i.second << endl;
    if (i.second == 1)
    {
      c++;
    }
  }

  cout << c;
}
```

When I try to switch the std::array over with a regular `int[3]`, and the map template parameters to `map<int*, int>`, the program seems to make the map `freq` reuse `tri`, even if I put it inside the while loop, as if an optimization.

Note that for working with `map<int*, int>` the statement for printing the map's contents would be

```
    cout << i.first << ' ' << i.second << endl;
```

My question is, why isn't the std::array experiencing technical difficulties here? What is the hidden magic underneath the `freq[tri]++` statement?

[Here's where I found the code.](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/binary-search/practice-problems/algorithm/counting-triangles/editorial/)

Comment: Why would you *want* to use a C-style array over a `std::array` (or `std::vector`)?

Comment: Performance, if at all that comes to play, or just the plainness of its usage :P

Comment: C-style arrays have *no* performance advantage over `std::array`.

Comment: @mushi `std::array` is a zero cost abstraction.  it is basically `template <typename T, std::size_t N> struct array{ T arr[N]; };` but it has some convenience functions.

Comment: Quit guessing about performance, that doesn't work.

Comment: Of course, even I'd use a std::array *any* day; that's a no-brainer. The question is: why the different behavior? Something to do with copy constructing the std::array contents every time I insert into the map?

Comment: std::array does range checking. It is not a zero cost abstraction. Anyway, the only way to know is to twst, and I don't know why std::array is obviously better if there is no difference.

Comment: @SebastianZander `at()` does range checking, not `operator[]`.  I've seen performance testing between raw arrays and `std::array` and the result are close enough to be the same.

Comment: Oh, you're right about range checking. I haven't used it in a while and had forgotten the details. But if you have to say the results are close enough to be the same that implies to me that they are not. Are there obvious costs for very tight loops for example? Another thing that adds cost is compilation time. It is simply the case that it takes longer to compile using std:array over raw arrays. This is not a trivial cost. Another is it does not decay to a pointer. But sometimes that is the semantic you want. I think there is a ptr()-method or something though.

Comment: @SebastianZander I couldn't tell you if it affects compilation times in any meaningful way.  The reason I say they results are close enough is because they change from run to run.  Micro benchmarking picks up all sorts of other things so the timings have a margin of error to them.  I've even seen `std::array` out perform a raw array with enough of a margin where you could actually say it was faster.  Anyways, `std::array` allows you to use a fixed sized array in places where you couldn't (take this for example) so it has use cases.  I'm hoping we'll get an `array_view` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `std::array` does not have an issue here is because it does not decay to a pointer unlike a raw array.  So, when you use `std::array` you get a copy of it in the map which is unique to the map.  When you use a raw array you get a pointer to that array and you would have to dynamically allocate them to get different arrays since you copy the pointer, not the array into the map.

Comment: `std::array` also has an `operator<` that gives the desired ordering, unlike a raw pointer.

Comment: @Blastfurnace True, but that is easy enough to fix by giving the map a custom comparator.

Comment: So how do I do this using a C-style array, if at all?

Comment: @mushi AFAIK, you can't.  Each array in the map needs it own store so you would have to use `new` (if you want to use a `int*` as the key type) which means you no longer are using an actual array.  This is one of the things `std::array` was built to solve.

Comment: I keep forgetting to manage my own memory these days. A `std::array` sure helps then.

Comment: Well, OP has `map<int*, int>` so the *only* thing it could store as key is a pointer. Decay only allows to "set" arrays as keys of the map. The issue with decay is that it allows the code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

As you described it:

```
int main()
{
  int n, c = 0; cin >> n;
  int tri[3];
  map<int*, int> freq;

  while (n--)
  {
    cin >> tri[0] >> tri[1] >> tri[2];
    sort(begin(tri), end(tri));
    freq[tri]++;
  }
```

The problem is that `tri` will have the same address on each iteration of the loop. And now that your map is storing an address of an array instead of a full copy of the array, you're going to be updating the previously stored value of `freq[tri]` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Now suppose I transfer the array inside the while loop: compiler optimization kicks in?